# How to access a tempfile object across 2 separate requests (was:views) in Django

Tags: django, temporary-files

Can't find a direct, head on answer to this.  Is there a way to access a tempfile in Django across 2 distinct views?  Say I have the following code:

```
view#1(request):
   temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
   write_book.save(temp_file)
   temp_file_name = temp_file.name
   print temp_file_name
   request.session['output_file_name'] = temp_file_name
   request.session.modified = True
   return #something or other

view#2(request):
   temp_file_name = request.session['output_file_name']
   temp_file = open(str(temp_file_name))
   #do something with 'temp_file' here
```

My problem comes in specifically on view#2, the 2nd line "open(temp_file_name)".  Django complains this file/pathway doesn't exist, which is consistent of my understanding of the tempfile module (that the file is 'hidden' and only available to Django).

Is there a way for me to access this file?  In case it matters, I ONLY need to read from it (technically serve it for download).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks seddonym for attempting to answer.  My partner clarified this for me...seddonym is correct for the *Django* version of NamedTemporaryFile.  By calling the python version (sorry, don't have enough cred to post hyperlinks.  Stupid rule) you CAN access across requests.

The trick is setting the delete=False parameter, and closing the file before 'returning' at the end of the request.  Then, in the subsequent request, just open(file_name).  Psuedo code below:

```
>>> import tempfile
>>> file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
>>> file.name
'c:\\users\\(blah)\(blah)\(blah)\\temp\\tmp9drcz9'
>>> file.close()
>>> file
<closed file '<fdopen>', mode 'w+b' at 0x00EF5390>
>>> f = open(file.name)
>>> f
<open file 'c:\users\ymalik\appdata\local\temp\tmp9drcz9', mode 'r' at 0x0278C128>
```

This is, of course, done in the console, but it works in django as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think of this as how to access a NamedTemporaryFile across different requests, rather than different views.  Looking at [this documentation on NamedTemporaryFile](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NamedTemporaryFile), it says that the file can be opened across the same process, but not necessarily across multiple processes.  Perhaps your other view is being called in a different Django process.

My suggestion would be to abandon the use of NamedTemporaryFile and instead just write it as a permanent file, then delete the file in the other view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The link you pasted is obviously official documentation, but other available information conflicts with this:                http://pymotw.com/2/tempfile/                                           part of note is about 1/3 down under the 'NamedTemporaryFile'  section

Comment: You're right, it's not part of the official Django documentation but it is on the wiki so it has a decent chance of being right! The documentation you posted is for the python standard implementation (`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`) so it may well behave differently.

Comment: Thanks again for trying.  I also edited my question to reflect your point about views versus requests.  You are 100% correct, I did mean requests.  Hopefully this will help someone if they are searching.